# pod install failed, cannot find exists

Tags: react-native

pod install fails and i get the error bellow:

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.  #  from /Users/sargsyann/Documents/any-ai/any_ai_code/ios/Podfile:13

I found the fix https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20757/files/628d4dd1f157d18b5ab35b8bb13459a008ba599a#diff-0dcf00099f7e7d81e0a6a5b35acbaf8ce0d187b6bd28c514a1d64b72ebd45214

But i cannot find the exists method in my code. So in Podfile there is no "exists" method.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried cd ios first? then try pod install.
if this don’t work try re installing your cocoapods.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not helps
> pod install --repo-update
Using Expo modules

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

 #  from /Users/sargsyann/Documents/any-ai/any_ai_code/ios/Podfile:13
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'AnyChat' do
 >    use_expo_modules!
 #    post_integrate do |installer|
 #  -------------------------------------------